# Популярные разрешения экранов Android

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста, под какое соотношение сторон экрана устройств Android стоит разрабатывать приложение, чтобы расползания изображения были у меньшего количества пользователей? 16:9 или 16:10, какие нынче популярные разрешения? Есть такая [табличка](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?hl=ru), но по ней не сильно понятно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изначально вы определяетесь, какую именно игру вы будете делать - 2D или 3D.
После смотрите на различных экранах получаемое растяжение картинки. Опираясь на полученные результаты, пытаетесь настроить камеру лучшим способом. В случае, когда этот метод не работает, вы можете попробовать разработать скрипт, добавляющий на экран черные полосы, но эта не лучшая практика. Лучше всего создавать изначально адаптивную картинку. Для этого стоит посмотреть настройки камеры по [этой](http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html) статье с использованием Occlusion Culling.
Что касается пользовательских интерфейсов и меню просмотрите статью ["Создание интерфейса (UI) под разные разрешения экрана"](http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html), а также ["Canvas Scaler"](http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html).
Для разработки для Android полезным будет просмотреть и [основные аспекты](http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/android-GettingStarted.html) разработки под эту платформу.

Comment: Игра 2D. Читал последние две статьи и по их примеру использую Canvas для элементов и делаю привязку к углам Anchors.